# Azure DocumentDB Decimal Truncation

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm currently using the Azure DocumentDB to store product data with prices. Nearly everything is working quite fine but now I have the issue that my decimals (System.Decimal) are being truncated when reading from DocumentDB.
For example this price:

```
Input Price: 25.1132356547854257645454
```

will be truncated into

```
DocumentDB Price: 25.113235654785
```

As we are using a sync mechanism to find price changes, this will result into a price change as it is not the same price anymore. 
I have no idea how I can change the behavior of the DocumentDB. In worst case I would have to truncate my input prices to prevent this problem, but I would rather not.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure DocumentDB uses [IEEE floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) per the JSON standard. This is required so that the data is portable across different programming platforms and applications. Unfortunately, this can lead to the truncation of large integers or higher precision decimal numbers like you're seeing.

To work around this, please consider breaking up the number to a two part number, representing as a string if you're only using for equality, or storing the truncated representation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now at least I know what causes this. I think I'll stick with truncation when inputting the data. It is not that big deal.